# #load fails to load shared .fsx

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

Why doesn't #load work

I've tried it in the same folder and in a relative folder as below

What am I missing?

run.fsx is

```
#load "../shared/shared.fsx"
let key = "MyKey"

let Run(message: string, log: TraceWriter, result: byref<string>) =
    result <- doItAll message key

    log.Info(sprintf "F# results: %s" result)
```

shared.fsx is

```
let doItAll message key = key + " has handled " + message
```

error is

```
run.fsx(x,y): error FS39: The value or constructor 'doItAll' is not defined
```

Comment: Note - make sure you have edited the host.json to set
{
 "watchDirectories": ["shared", "shared-fs"]
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not specify a namespace or a module name explicitly in `shared.fsx`, then the F# compiler will put the code in the file in an implicitly named module `Shared`. You should be able to fix the error by adding `open Shared`:

```
#load "../shared/shared.fsx"
open Shared

let key = "MyKey"

let Run(message: string, log: TraceWriter, result: byref<string>) =
    result <- doItAll message key    
    log.Info(sprintf "F# results: %s" result)
```

If you want to control the naming yourself, you can also add `module` declaration in `shared.fsx` and give an explicit name yourself:

```
module SharedStuff

let doItAll message key = key + " has handled " + message
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas - that's the bit that isn't clear

Also for clarification it's a big S on the front of the filename irrespective of the filename case.

Comment: @DavidLapeš Yes, F# capitalizes the first letter - I'm not quite sure what the rules are, so using an explicit module name is always a safer option :)